# My autoloader loads the class file but gives a fatal errors for the class

Tags: php, class, namespaces, spl-autoload-register

I have my run.php file (the file that gets executed on the backend):

```
<?php
spl_autoload_register(function ($class) {
    $class = str_replace('\\', '/', $class);
    echo 'classes/' . $class . '/' . $class . '.php';
    require 'classes/' . $class . '/' . $class . '.php';
}); 

try {
    echo "General Greeting - Begin run\n";
    $main = new Main();
} catch(\Exception $e) {
    echo "Normal: " . $e->getMessage();
} catch(\PDOException $e) {
    echo "PDO: " . $e->getTraceAsString();
}
```

I have my Main() class located in ./classes/Main/Main.php (relative to run.php)

```
<?php
namespace Main;

class Main {
    public function __construct() {
        echo "test";
    }
}
```

And when I execute run.php this is my console output:

> General Greeting - Begin run
>
> classes/Main/Main.php
>
> Fatal error: Class 'Main' not found in run.php on line 9

It requires the class file correctly and all, so my thinking is probably that I'm doing something wrong with the namespaces, however, I re-read the documentation and can't, for the life of me, figure out why it is giving me this error.

Comment: should that not be either `new Main\Main()` or `use Main;` at the start? What I want to say is: You do not declare the namespace that the class Main should be taken from.

Comment: Aha, I see what you're getting at here. Thank you @ArSeN. Would you maybe like to change that to an answer? I'd be happy to do it otherwise.